# Pull one record from the database and bind to an HTML tag

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET, what is the definitive way to pull one record from the database and bind it and HTML tag? Brevity and style points count.

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, you'll want to use the SqlDataSource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommandType="Text"
    SelectCommand="select MyField FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @id"
    >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUserName" PropertyName="Text" Name="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:BulletedList runat="server" DataTextField="MyField" DataSourceID="sql">
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want but, [detailsview control](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/detailsview.aspx) is designed for displaying only one record from data source.

> DetailsView is a data-bound user
>   interface control that renders a
>   single record at a time from its
>   associated data source, optionally
>   providing paging buttons to navigate
>   between records.